# WPF command binding with input validation - how to enable the "save" button only if all input is valid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, idataerrorinfo, relaycommand

In my ViewModel I have implemented `IDataErrorInfo` interface (along with `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Input validation works as intended, I have no problems there.

I have this property as part of `IDataErrorInfo`

```cs
public string Error { get { return this[null]; } }
```

To my understanding, `Error` should be empty if all validated inputs pass validation, so I pass this as my CanExecute method

```cs
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);
```

But, my "save" button never gets enabled. My guess is that `CanExecuteChanged` never gets triggered. If that's true, where and how should I trigger it?

---

This is my `RelayCommand` class. I have tried other ways of implementation, but the results were the same. I think it works, because the "save" button is enabled  if I don't pass `CanExecute` method to the constructor.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || canExecute();      
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    
    public void Execute(object parameter) { execute(); }
}
```

The "save" button:

```xml
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding InsertCommand}"/>
```

InsertCommand:

```cs
public RelayCommand InsertCommand { get; internal set; }
```

In the ViewModel constructor:

```cs
InsertCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteInsert, CanExecuteInsert);
```

CanExecute:

```cs
bool CanExecuteInsert()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);
}
```

Comment: Show InsertCommand how it was initialized and its CanExecute

Comment: @lll Added it at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't really added enough code for us to accurately tell you what your problem is. However, you are taking the correct approach. I also use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface, but I added some extra properties into my base class that implements it:

```cs
public string Error // actual IDataErrorInfo Member
{
    get
    {
        if (!HasError)
            return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string error in Errors)
            errors.AppendUniqueOnNewLineIfNotEmpty(error);
        return errors.ToString();
    }
}
```

```cs
public virtual ObservableCollection<string> Errors
{
    get { return errors; }
}

public virtual bool HasError
{
    get { return Errors != null && Errors.Count > 0; }
}
```

The `Errors` collection just enables me to maintain multiple errors simultaneously and `HasError` just tells me if there are any errors or not.  The `Errors` collection is filled using the `IDataErrorInfo` indexer in each data type:

```cs
public override ObservableCollection<string> Errors
{
    get
    {
        errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["Title"]);
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["Artist"]);
        // ...
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["DealerPrice"]);
        return errors;
    }
}
```

So to answer your actual question, I would handle the `CanExecute` functionality of the `Save Command` like this:

```cs
public override ICommand Save
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => SaveCommand(), canExecute => 
            CanSave(DigitalServiceProviderPriceTier)); }
}
// ...
private bool CanSave(DigitalServiceProviderPriceTier digitalServiceProviderPriceTier)
{
    return digitalServiceProviderPriceTier != null && 
        digitalServiceProviderPriceTier.HasChanges && 
        !digitalServiceProviderPriceTier.HasError; // <-- Important part
}
```

So, it seems as though you are doing this in *almost* the same way - my additional properties are of course optional. If your `Error` property is never empty, then I would say that *that* is your problem. Start by debugging it and seeing what value it actually has... perhaps there is always an error there that shouldn't be?

Ahhhh... I just noticed your `Error` property code... *that* is your problem:

```cs
public string Error { get { return this[null]; } }
```

You are calling the indexer with a value of `null`, so what the code in your indexer is returning is actually what your `Error` property value will be. An indexer should also return an empty string if there are no validation errors:

```cs
public override string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        if (propertyName == "SomePropertyName" && SomePropertyName.IsNullOrEmpty()) 
            error = "You must enter some property.";
        if (propertyName == "OtherPropertyName" && OtherPropertyName.Length != 3) 
            error = "The OtherPropertyName must be 3 characters long.";
        // ...
        return error;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Error` property, you should call the *actual* property names that you want to validate as I did in my `Errors` property and *not* `null`. So in the example above, you could call something like this in your `Error` property:

```cs
string error = this["SomePropertyName"];
if (error == string.Empty)
    error = this["OtherPropertyName"];
return error;
```

Once again, I've written too much information... I just hope it all makes sense to you and you're not going to return with dozens of new questions. Hopefully, it's clear enough.

Comment: I started with WPF just recently, and in all the examples for IDataErrorInfo, the Error property was implemented like that. It works for validation, so I didn't think that was a problem.
I will try your suggestions when I get home.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I also had a logic flaw here 
`return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);`
It should go without negation, of course.