# Retrieving IDataErrorInfo string result in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I am after how I could get the string from the IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName] method from my ViewModel.

basically, I have created a new property inside the model so I could validate each row in the model collection, and on my vaildation check, I will say if its valid or not and if not, it will disable the command in my viewmodel

Model

```
   string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            // Vaildation logic

            if (result != string.Empty)
            {
                IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsValid = true;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

ViewModel

```
    public bool CanSave
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_ProductVersion != null && m_ProductVersion.ProductItems != null)
            {
                foreach (ProductItem item in m_ProductVersion.ProductItems)
                {
                    // I dont want to use isValid any more
                    if (!item.IsValid)
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

But I would like to get rid of the isValid Property if I can and use the result from the IDataErrorInfo inside the viewmodel.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all note, that your `IsValid` isn’t working correctly. Imagine you have 3 properties which you want to validate: `A`, `B` and `C`. WPF usually evaluates `IDataErrorInfo` whenever you enter something, so imagine I enter something invalid for `A` and `B`. I get an error and `IsValid` will be `false`. So far so good. Now, I enter something valid for `C`. `A` and `B` are still invalid, but `IsValid` will now be true—because the last `IDataErrorInfo` check yielded an empty result.

So your `IsValid` only checks the *last* property that was validated, which is definitely not enough for a general validity check.

A propert `IsValid` should run the validation for *every property* before returning a result. Something like this:

```
public bool IsValid ()
{
    for (string propertyName in allPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!string.IsEmptyOrNull(((IDataErrorInfo)this)[propertyName]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You need to maintain a list of all property names so we can iterate through those. Then we delegate the validation to `this[propertyName]` which calls the `IDataErrorInfo` validation. If we get *any* error, the object is not valid.

So, as you can see, you can replace a *single* property check with simply calling the `IDataErrorInfo` item property, but you usually want to do a check for *all* properties.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have implemented the `IDataErrorInfo` interface incorrectly. Please take a look at my answer to the long-titled [WPF command binding with input validation - how to enable the “save” button only if all input is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110880/wpf-command-binding-with-input-validation-how-to-enable-the-save-button-only/23112003#23112003) question on Stack Overflow for an example. Having set up the interface in this way (you can ignore the additional properties 'Errors', etc.), then you can access the error `string` simply like this:

```
string error = dataItem.Error;
```

If you extend the functionality of the interface like my example shows, then you could handle multiple errors and you could do this:

```
ObservableCollection<string> errors = dataItem.Errors;
```

Or this:

```
public bool CanSave
{
    get { return !dataItem.HasErrors; }
}
```

Comment: With this setup what are you doing to cause the errors collection to update/repoll itself when one of the validated controls has its value modified?

Comment: Hi @DanNeely, look at my linked answer. Each time the `Error` property is called, it checks the `HasErrors` property, which calls the `Errors` property, which kicks off the whole validation process again. Alternatively, you can just notify of property changes to the `Errors` collection from each property being validated (in addition to each property).